# How to convert dynamic variable from PHP syntax to twig

Tags: php, twig, opencart

I got PHP syntax:

```
<?php echo ${'method_courier_' . $zone['zone_id'] . '_free_shipping_from'}; ?>
```

How to convert it to Twig template engine syntax?

Comment: Yup, it's look that your link is the same what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ 'method_courier_' ~ zone.zone_id ~ '_free_shipping_from' }}
```

Comment: Hi! This is return for me not variable, but just string. It returns: method_courier_4_free_shipping_from but all this name should be like variable

Comment: you can store it in a variable like
set str1 = 'method_courier_' ~ zone.zone_id ~ '_free_shipping_from';